# SignalR and OpenId Connect

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid, openiddict

I have a server which uses `ASP.NET Core Web Api` and `OpenIddict` as authorization framework. Now I've added an [`SignalR`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) host and want to add authorisation to it.

From [different sources](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2782#issuecomment-31270853) I found that `SignalR` (JS Client) wants that you send the access token in the querystring or by cookie as websockets don't support headers.

As the authentication middleware doesn't check the querystring or cookie container for an authorization entry I need to implement such an provider/retriever/resolver which reads this value by myself.

I've found a [solution for `IdentityServer`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/357#issuecomment-55708001) but nothing about `OpenIddict`.

Where/How do I implement such an token resolver with `OpenIddict`?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/mikebridge/IdentityServer4SignalR) what you're trying to do?  It has [two levels of middleware](https://github.com/mikebridge/IdentityServer4SignalR/blob/master/src/ChatAPI/Auth/JWTInitialization.cs#L80-L87) to accept both the query string and the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `JwtBearerAuthentication` then you can use `OnMessageReceived` to set token:

```
Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
   OnMessageReceived = async (ctx) =>
   {
        ctx.Token = ctx.Request.Query["<qs-name>"];
   }
}
```

Or if you use `IdentityServerAuthentication` then you can use `TokenRetriever`(not tested but it should be something like this):

```
   TokenRetriever = (ctx) =>
   {
        return ctx.Request.Query["<qs-name>"];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @adem-caglin mentioned, in IdentityserverAuthentication you use TokenRetriever and can go with the built-in functions if what you're after is the standard bearer header or a query string

```
TokenRetriever = (request) => 
{
    // by default calls TokenRetrieval.FromAuthorizationHeader()(request);
    // check if request is to signalr endpoint and only then apply FromQueryString
    return TokenRetrieval.FromQueryString()(request);
}
```