# JWT authentication in SignalR Core from Angular

Tags: authentication, signalr, jwt, openiddict, asp.net-core-signalr

The post is almost duplicate as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193171/jwt-authentication-in-signalr-net-core-without-passing-token-in-query-string) question, but I am using new SignalRCore (1.0.0 alpha2).
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-final" />`

In my .NET Core 2.0 I use OpenIddict to authenticate user on server. On client I use [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt).

Now I need to know how can I connect on server with `Authorization header access_token`? I would assume that I should use custom request header when trying to connect on server.

Can this be done with new SignalR Core? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api) thread which mention that websockets does not support custom headers but I wonder if SignalR Core team did some magic to support this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible when you are using JavaScript client because some underlying APIs (like webSocket) don't allow setting headers. This is why you need to use queryString. Also, this [thread on github](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/888) may be useful.

If you are using the C# client setting headers is not possible at the moment but this is just a limitation of the API and should be fixed in the future.

**EDIT**

SignalR now has API that allows to pass JWT token to both C# and JavaScript client. It is also now possible to set headers when using C# client.